# Save typedef enum objects in NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, enums

I have written the following code:

```
typedef enum {
    kProductList,
    kProductGrid,
    kProductSingleView
} ProductViewType;

ProductViewType ViewType;
```

In my view change method, I am changing the ViewType. When the app closes I want to save the last ViewType in a UserDefauls, so that when first time load, I can check users last ViewType and set it to default.

I have written the following code:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:ViewType forKey:@"ProductViewType"];
```

But XCode shows an warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion.

any solutions ? thanks.

Answer (score 18):

`NSUserDefaults` stored *objects* not C data types.

Not tried this but you might be able to get away with just the following change:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@(ViewType) forKey:@"ProductViewType"];
```

The `@()` notation is short-hand for `[NSNumber numberWithInt:viewType]`.

Comment: I write your code but XCode shows an error: extraneous "]" before ";"

Comment: anyway, thanks for your information, I have done with some manual integers value to check the states and solved my problem.

Comment: I am suggesting only three extra characters to your code, none of which are square brackets, so I think it's unlikely that my code results in your error.

Comment: This worked for me. Nice bit of short-hand I didn't know about.

Comment: @stephen how to retrieve this value and again assign this to enum object?

like 

thePlayerState  = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectforKey:@"ProductViewType"];
???

Please help

Comment: @iAhmed Use the `integerForKey:` method.

Answer (score 3):

As stated [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) NSUserDefaults' `setObject:forKey:` method only acceps objects. Since enum type is not an object, you cannot set it with this method. Since enums are basically integers by default, you can use `setInteger:forKey:` method to store your value.

Answer (score 1):

Because `ViewType` isn't an object.

You can put ViewType inside a `NSValue` first.

```
NSValue *value = [NSValue value:&ViewType withObjCType:@encode(ProductViewType)];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:value forKey:@"ProductViewType"];
```

Comment: your code runs, but when I printed ProductViewType, it prints (ViewType), not the views values. I don't know why, but thanks. and I am now tracking the viewtype using some static integer values.

Comment: +value:withObjCType: will be deprecated and one should instead use +valueWithBytes:objCType:. Apart from that, NSUserDefaults doesn't accept NSValue object (anymore?), only  NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary.

Answer (score 1):

enums are integers, setObject requires object!!!

Encapsulate this enum in an object (may be a NSValue or eve a custom class). Then write it to UserDefaults.

Or if you are using XCode4,

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@(ViewType) forKey:@"ProductViewType"];
```